# Testing an AWS SNS Util Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write the unit tests for this util class.(I am not very experienced in writing unit tests) I want to test the following:

1. It throws an NPE on providing a null arn.
2. A non null AmazonSNS is initialised as a result of this.

   @Singleton
   @Slf4j
   public class SNSClientUtil {

   ```
   @Inject
   private MadonnaConfig madonnaConfig;

   public AmazonSNS getSNSClient(String snsTopicArn) {
       return AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
               .withCredentials(new OdinAWSCredentialsProvider(madonnaConfig.getSnsOdinMaterialSet()))
               .withRegion(Regions.fromName(getRegionNameFromARN(snsTopicArn)))
               .build();
   }

   private String getRegionNameFromARN(String arn) {
       String[] tokens = arn.split(":");
       return tokens[3];
   }
   ```

   }

I am using Mockito. This is my test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SNSClientUtilTest {

    @Mock
    SNSClientUtil snsClientUtil;

    private String topicARN = "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:123456789:Notifications-Devo";
    private String regionName = "ap-south-1";

    @Before
    public void setup() {

    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testNullTopicARN() {
        snsClientUtil.getSNSClient(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSNSClientCreation() {
        AmazonSNSClientBuilder builder = Mockito.mock(AmazonSNSClientBuilder.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        Mockito.when(builder.build()).thenReturn(Mockito.any(AmazonSNS.class));
        AmazonSNS sns = snsClientUtil.getSNSClient(topicARN);
        Assert.assertNotNull(sns);
    }
}
```

The null pointer test was failing. So I tried to test the creation of a non null SNS client by mocking the AmazonSNSClientBuilder. But that gives the following exception :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClientBuilder
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types

at com.amazon.madonnaservice.test.utils.SNSClientUtilTest.testRegionNameFromARN(SNSClientUtilTest.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(Unknown Source)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito gives you the error

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  Cannot mock/spy class
>   com.amazonaws.services.sns.AmazonSNSClientBuilder Mockito cannot
>   mock/spy following:
>     - final classes
>     - anonymous classes
>     - primitive types

And `public final class AmazonSNSClientBuilder` is final
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClientBuilder.html

So your mockito setup is **invalid**. Maybe you can use another api from amazon that you can mock, otherwise you need to introduce a layer that wraps the client that you can mock in your unit test.

Comment: How can I introduce a layer to wrap the client?

Comment: Add a java Interface that hides the real `AmazonSNSClientBuilder` client. In the real code you resolve this as real thing and in the test you mock your Interface with Mockito. You need some kind of dependency injection to get it going. If you don't want to add a framework for it you can just do it with a constructor.

Comment: Would you recommed doing this for a class that is already a ClientUtil? It looks to me that the class I am writing is itself that wrapper.

Comment: Hard to say without knowledge about you code base. If you see two obvious solutions try en both and stick with the one you like the most!